# How to display single channel in graph editor / dopesheet?

Tags: graph-editor, dopesheet

I ussually use hide/unhide , so for every single channel i want to solo, i have to press shift-H (reveal the selected one and hide another). But i feel it's to slow doing it over and over again. is there no setup for this really ? or it's hidden somewhere. Because this is a very basic feature that's missing.

Comment: In the view menu of the graph editor you can enable **Only Selected Curve Keyframes**

Comment: Yeah that is a mouse cursor icon.

Comment: I can't use that. What i want is to display the selected channel only so if i use 'frame all' it will fit only those channel curve. Using hide/unhide works perfectly. But turn ON  'only selected curve keyframes' will have no effect.